# .net: What is the correct format string for a fixed number of decimal places, but "x.xxE+xxx" for large numbers?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I want to format double values with a fixed number of four decimal places. What I want:

- "Small" numbers should be displayed in whole, i.e., 1234.56789 should be displayed as 1234.5679
- "Large" numbers should be displayed in exponential notation

I am not able to achieve both:

```
(1234.56789).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

yields:

```
1234.5679
```

But:

```
(123456789123456789.123456789).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

yields:

```
1234567891234567000.0000
```

Using `G4` yields `1.235E+17` for the large number and `1235` for the small one.

I also tried "E4" and "e4" without any good result.

So, what format should I use to achieve the same behavior as for the default format, i.e., when not using a default string, but chopping down the decimal places to four? It cannot be that I am forced to do string hacking or have to do "ifs" to check if the number is in a specific range...

Comment: Use the return value of Math.Log10(value) to decide whether you like "F4" or "E".

Answer (score 0):

Use G8 it will give you the result you want

```
(1234.56789).ToString("G8", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

output: 1234.5679

```
(123456789123456789.123456789).ToString("G8", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

output: 1.2345679E+17

Comment: No, when I apply this to 1.23456789, it gets me 1.2345679 instead of 1.2346. I always want to have four decimal places.